# How to verify if a key is into array in Behat

Tags: php, behavior, behat, gherkin

I have a problem with my test in behat. So I have the scenario :

```
Scenario: Teste la route /settlement/rank/types
Given I request "http:/localhost/admin"
Then  the response should be JSON
And   I should have code with value 200
And   I should have error with value 0
And   The response has a "aUser" property
And   This property "aUser" is not empty
And   The property "aUser" has the keys:
          |id_user |login |first_name |last_name |email |id_company |enable |id_language |label_language |
```

Now the FeatureContext is :

```
/**
 * @Given /^The property "([^"]*)" has the keys:$/
 */
public function thePropertyHasTheKeys($aProperty, TableNode $table){
    $data = json_decode($this->_response->getBody(true),true);
    foreach($table as $value){
        print_r($value['id_user']);
        if(!in_array($value,$data['data'][$aProperty])){
            throw new Exception("The property ".$value. " is not set\n");
        }
    }
}
```

In `$data` I have an array with this form :

```
|id_user |login |first_name |last_name |email |id_company |enable |id_language |label_language |
```

So I want to compare the array `$data` with the array `$table`, if the key are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
$data = json_decode($this->_response->getBody(true),true);
foreach($table as $key=>$value)
{

    if( !isset($data[$key]) ) { throw new Exception("The key ".$key. " is not set\n"); }
    if( $data[$key]!=$value ) { throw new Exception("The value ".$value. " is wrong\n"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to reuse other people's code to make it a little more obvious as to what is going on - in this case, PHPunit goes well with a lot of things:

```
// outside the test class
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/Assert/Functions.php';

// convert $table to a clean array ....

// compare
$data = json_decode($this->_response->getBody(true), true);
assertEquals($table, $data, 'Decoded JSON does not match the given example');
```